# Manipulate @FormParam for sanitizing XSS values

Tags: java, jersey

I am using `@FormParam` from `jsr311-api-1.0.jar` in an old project with Jersey 1.0.3. Is there a way to add a filter which sanitizes and changes all the `@FormParam`s that I am using in the application?

Example code is as follows:

```java
@POST
@Path("myMethod")
public String myMethod(@FormParam("data") String data) {
    // Need to change the value of this data to clean XSS
    // Code to save data into database
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the [JAX-RS 1.0 API](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) ([JSR 311](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)) do not provide filters or interceptors, you could consider sanitizing the input in your resource methods.

To do it, you could consider [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/). Here is an example provided by the documentation:

```java
String unsafe = 
  "<p><a href='http://example.com/' onclick='stealCookies()'>Link</a></p>";
String safe = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, Whitelist.basic());
```

[OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://github.com/OWASP/java-html-sanitizer) can do the trick too. Here is an example provided by the documentation:

```java
PolicyFactory policy = new HtmlPolicyBuilder()
    .allowElements("a")
    .allowUrlProtocols("https")
    .allowAttributes("href").onElements("a")
    .requireRelNofollowOnLinks()
    .toFactory();
String safeHTML = policy.sanitize(untrustedHTML);
```

---

If you are willing to use the Jersey API, it's worth mention that Jersey 1.x provides the [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.0.3/jersey/com/sun/jersey/spi/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) interface that you can implement and modify the state of the request.